# Open response in a popup when submitting a form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, popup

I will like to open some sort of thank you popup after submitting my form. I am using this form script: http://www.mattvarone.com/web-design/simpleform-php-email-script which already has responses but will only appear inline.

Please help! Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: Consider using a dialog box or modal. I would suggest jQuery and the jQuery UI Dialog module. http://jquery.com/ http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a javascript [`alert()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp) function to your form's `onsubmit` event?  If the form's already calling a function you could always add in an alert statement at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript `checkform.js`, you might need to change this part:

```
if ( passed == false ) 
{
    // responce = alertText.replace('#name', eLabel); // Comment this out
    alert( responce ); // Let just the response be there
    next.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Or the best suggestion I would say is to use a Modal Window plugin using jQuery or something like: http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery plugin for a popup window,and then use the `.popup()` function it includes.
You can download the popup plugin from [here](http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html)